# Css hollow circle with shadow

Tags: css, sass

I have a nice red glow effect but only on the text of my button, not on the border :

```css
body{
 background: black;
}
.delete-button-container{
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      padding: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
    
.delete-button{
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    font-size: large;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
      0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
      0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
      0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
      0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="delete-button-container">
   <div class="delete-button">X</div>
</div>
```

do I have no other option then to create my own png for this and apply a drop-shadow to that or is there a trick to apply a shadow to borders?

Comment: Have a look at filters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aboaEjR - box-shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);

/* and */
box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 2px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1),
 0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a nice red glow effect but only on the text of my button, not on the border

What is the problem of applying the same values to a `box-shadow` property?

**Result**

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.delete-button-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.delete-button {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: large;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="delete-button-container">
  <div class="delete-button">X</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: that's really quite good, any chance you know of a way to have the shadow on the inside as well?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a `box-shadow` applied.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.delete-button-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.delete-button {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  font-size: large;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 6px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1), 0 0 7px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(255, 50, 50, .75);
}
```

```html
<div class="delete-button-container">
  <div class="delete-button">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered box-shadow? See this example:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 50, 50, 1);
```